# Are Stacks and Queue's considered LinkedList?

Tags: queue, stack

Are Stacks and Queue considered LinkedList?

The time complexity of indexing a LinkedList is 0(n). So am I right to assume that's the same for stacks and queues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Stacks and Queues are logical data structures that describe the operations you can perform on them.

Both a Stack and Queue can be implemented by an underlying linked list or a continuous memory array (or, TBH, any number of other implementations you could think of). The time complexity of any operation on a queue or a stack would depend on the underlying implementation.

Comment: For the java Stack<T> stack = new Stack<>(); That class extends vector so it would share the same time complexity as a dynamic array right?